# movie banner image to carousel in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

For movies reviews App in rails i need to add carousel where movie banner should be display in the carousel. when adding new movie, banner image should also upload along with the image. so the banner image should go in to carousel. I should limit carousel to ten sliders. The newly added movie banner should be display in first slider. can anyone help me in this regards.

Comment: What have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: I am uploading movie images using paperclip gem. this is my movies model class Movie < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 
 has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "162x238#" }
   validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end I need to add one more banner tag to the movies model where i can call it in my carousel

Answer (score 0):

get all images into instance variable and use that instance variable in jquery carousel.